# Add CSS transition for toggle image in jQuery

Tags: jquery, css

I would like to add a transition (fade in/fade out) between my toggle images. That's possible ?

http://jsfiddle.net/Xroad/rY8Bq/

```
$(function(){

var $toggleImg = $('.toggleImg');

    function fnToggleImg(e){
        if (e.type == 'click') {
            $(this).data('clicked', !$(this).data('clicked'));
        } else if (!$(this).data('clicked')) {
            this.src = this.src.indexOf('-hover') == -1 ? this.src.replace("-normal", "-hover") : this.src.replace("-hover", "-normal");
        }
    }

    if (Modernizr.touch){
        $toggleImg.hammer();

            $('img.rollover').on('touchstart touchend', fnToggleImg);
         } else {
            $('img.rollover').on('mouseenter mouseleave', fnToggleImg);
    }

$toggleImg.on(Modernizr.touch ? 'tap' : 'click', fnToggleImg);

});
```

Comment: Since it appears all you are doing is changing the `src`, then there is no CSS to change..thus no transition. You would have to use JQ animations. A JSFiddle would be useful however.

Comment: Ok I created a JSFiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/Xroad/rY8Bq/
I would like to create the CSS transition effect on my image button

Answer (score 0):

Jquery .toggle() uses the 'display' property, but there are no css transitions available for this.

But you can use the buit in Jquery transitions with toggle [Go down this page for examples](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/)

Comment: Thank you, and compared to my code where I need to add the "slow" property ?

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way would be to create a class and toggle the class using jquery.

Your default class will have transition property set along with timing and the initial property like opacity: 0; and a new class can be then added which will have opacity 1; set. This will trigger the css transition on click/toggle.

Hope that helped.

Comment: I tried with CSS but the new image that appears is invisible due to the opacity: 0